# Biholomorphic function between given set and open unit disk

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $A=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|<1, |z-1|<1\}$.

From Riemann mapping theorem we know that there exist biholomorphic function between $A$ and open unit disk.

How to construct these function ?

I tried to apply Möbius transformation and classical mappings ( exponent, $z^2$, etc.) but I doesn't work. I need only hints for this problem.

Comment: There is no way since the unit disk is closed and $A$ is open.

Comment: Unit disk is open : $\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|<1\}$.

Comment: How on earth are people voting to close this as off topic? This is very much on topic.

Comment: @mikis: that is the unit ball.

Comment: @JamesS.Cook: where are the OP efforts to solve this problem?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: Ok, My mistake in translation. I need only hints, not full solution.

Comment: The system works! On hold -> Improve -> Reopen! (With two reopen votes coming from people who voted to close, too!)

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Maybe a better plan of attack, instead of immediately voting to close the question, is to only offer the OP hints.  This way, they have a concrete way forward, but are still forced to engage the problem in order to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The circles $\{|z|=1\}$ and $\{|z-1|=1\}$ intersect at two points $a,\bar a\in\mathbb{C}$, $\operatorname{Im}a>0$. The Möbius mapping
$$
\phi(z)=\frac{z-a}{z-\bar a}
$$
transforms $A$ into an angle with vertex at $0$. A power function transforms this into a half plane, and another Möbius mapping transforms it in the open unit disk.

Comment: This type of region (bounded by two circular arcs) is called a "lune".   Discussions of conformal mappings generally include this as a good example.  With Julian's method to work with them.